# Powershell: regexp is not applied infact serveral test say its correct

Tags: regex, powershell

i have a pretty dirty file, its the output of PM2 when you pipe it to a .txt-file.
Looks like this:

```
ÔöîÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÉ
Ôöé id Ôöé name                    Ôöé version Ôöé mode    Ôöé pid      Ôöé uptime Ôöé Ôå║    Ôöé status   Ôöé cpu      Ôöé mem      Ôöé user     Ôöé watching Ôöé
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöñ
Ôöé 0  Ôöé Backendserver           Ôöé 0.0.1   Ôöé fork    Ôöé 60168    Ôöé 2D     Ôöé 0    Ôöé online   Ôöé 0%       Ôöé 563.4mb  Ôöé AdminisÔÇª Ôöé disabled Ôöé
Ôöé 1  Ôöé Frontendserver          Ôöé N/A     Ôöé fork    Ôöé 25976    Ôöé 2D     Ôöé 0    Ôöé online   Ôöé 0%       Ôöé 71.3mb   Ôöé AdminisÔÇª Ôöé disabled Ôöé
Ôöé 2  Ôöé Schedulingservice       Ôöé N/A     Ôöé fork    Ôöé 38904    Ôöé 2D     Ôöé 0    Ôöé online   Ôöé 0%       Ôöé 58.9mb   Ôöé AdminisÔÇª Ôöé disabled Ôöé
Ôöé 3  Ôöé edi-csv-server          Ôöé 0.0.1   Ôöé fork    Ôöé 46728    Ôöé 2D     Ôöé 0    Ôöé online   Ôöé 0%       Ôöé 54.7mb   Ôöé AdminisÔÇª Ôöé disabled Ôöé
Ôöé 5  Ôöé edi-frontendserver      Ôöé N/A     Ôöé fork    Ôöé 49584    Ôöé 2D     Ôöé 0    Ôöé online   Ôöé 0%       Ôöé 56.5mb   Ôöé AdminisÔÇª Ôöé disabled Ôöé
Ôöé 4  Ôöé edi-sybase-inferface    Ôöé 0.0.1   Ôöé fork    Ôöé 31156    Ôöé 2D     Ôöé 0    Ôöé online   Ôöé 0%       Ôöé 60.2mb   Ôöé AdminisÔÇª Ôöé disabled Ôöé
ÔööÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÿ
host metrics | cpu: 2.8% | mem: 46.2% | net: 64.8ms Ôçô 0.001mb/s Ôçæ 0.003mb/s | disk: Ôçô 0mb/s Ôçæ 0mb/s |
```

So i have a small powershell scripts to remove the crazy symbols, because i want to use it later on in an c# application, but formatting and readability should be made via powershell.

```
$c = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\taut\Documents\git\PM2\PM2\scripts\test.txt" -Encoding UTF8
$c -replace '/[ÔöîÇ¼éåçôöÉªæ┤╝| ]/', ''
New-Item -Path "C:\Users\taut\Documents\git\PM2\PM2\scripts\new.txt" | Set-Content -Value $c -Encoding UTF8
```

But my problem is, the new file contains exactly the same as the source file.
I tried regex101.com and regexr.com both said my regexpression is correct.

Thank you very much guys, i have no clue where the issue comes from.

Comment: @Theo already tried that, doenst work, same result... also tried to assign the result to a different variable but still doesnt work.

Comment: The file looks like it's using extended ASCII characters or some kind of terminal controls to draw a table. With wrong encoding being used, the characters are converted to alphabets.

Comment: _my regexpression is correct_ ? I think not. The forward slashes before and after the square brackets should not be there, you are trying to also remove space characters and your missing a couple of characters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As commented, the way your code should work is by capturing the result of the `-replace` action back into the `c$` variable using `$c = $c -replace '[ÔöîÇ¼éåçôöÉªæ┤╝|£ñÿ]'`.
Then use that to write the new file.

As you can see, your regex string is wrong; it should be `[ÔöîÇ¼éåçôöÉªæ┤╝|£ñÿ]`

Also, you don't need the `New-Item` in there and you can pipe the replaced text straight through to `Set-Content` like this:

```
$c = Get-Content -Path "D:\Test\blah.txt" -Encoding UTF8
$c -replace '[ÔöîÇ¼éåçôöÉªæ┤╝|£ñÿ]' |  Set-Content -Path "D:\Test\new.txt" -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: As metioned in my comment, that doesnt work either.

Comment: @FlorianTaut Don't downvote this. Your regex was totally wrong and you should try the code out first. Also, your question does not show what you have tried already! In fact, you even boast that your regex expression is correct, while it is clearly not.

Comment: Sorry bout that, the regexp you proved later after i voted worked, but the space char should be there because i wanted to remove all spaced as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can extract data from that awful text using `ConvertFrom-String`

First we provide some "training" data in a template.

```
$template = @'
ÔöîÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÉ
Ôöé id Ôöé name                    Ôöé version Ôöé mode    Ôöé pid      Ôöé uptime Ôöé Ôå║    Ôöé status   Ôöé cpu      Ôöé mem      Ôöé user     Ôöé watching Ôöé
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöñ
Ôöé 0  Ôöé {Host*:Backendserver}           Ôöé {Version:0.0.1}   Ôöé {Mode:fork}    Ôöé {PID:60168}    Ôöé {Uptime:2D}     Ôöé 0    Ôöé {Status:online}   Ôöé {CPU:0%}       Ôöé {Mem:563.4mb}  Ôöé {User:Adminis}ÔÇª Ôöé {Watching:disabled} Ôöé
Ôöé 1  Ôöé {Host*:Frontendserver}          Ôöé {Version:N/A}     Ôöé {Mode:fork}    Ôöé {PID:25976}    Ôöé {Uptime:2D}     Ôöé 0    Ôöé {Status:online}   Ôöé {CPU:0%}       Ôöé {Mem:71.3mb}   Ôöé {User:Adminis}ÔÇª Ôöé {Watching:disabled} Ôöé
ÔööÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÿ
'@
```

Now we use this template to extract the data

```
@'
ÔöîÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö¼ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÉ
Ôöé id Ôöé name                    Ôöé version Ôöé mode    Ôöé pid      Ôöé uptime Ôöé Ôå║    Ôöé status   Ôöé cpu      Ôöé mem      Ôöé user     Ôöé watching Ôöé
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö╝ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöñ
Ôöé 0  Ôöé Backendserver           Ôöé 0.0.1   Ôöé fork    Ôöé 60168    Ôöé 2D     Ôöé 0    Ôöé online   Ôöé 0%       Ôöé 563.4mb  Ôöé AdminisÔÇª Ôöé disabled Ôöé
Ôöé 1  Ôöé Frontendserver          Ôöé N/A     Ôöé fork    Ôöé 25976    Ôöé 2D     Ôöé 0    Ôöé online   Ôöé 0%       Ôöé 71.3mb   Ôöé AdminisÔÇª Ôöé disabled Ôöé
Ôöé 2  Ôöé Schedulingservice       Ôöé N/A     Ôöé fork    Ôöé 38904    Ôöé 2D     Ôöé 0    Ôöé online   Ôöé 0%       Ôöé 58.9mb   Ôöé AdminisÔÇª Ôöé disabled Ôöé
Ôöé 3  Ôöé edi-csv-server          Ôöé 0.0.1   Ôöé fork    Ôöé 46728    Ôöé 2D     Ôöé 0    Ôöé online   Ôöé 0%       Ôöé 54.7mb   Ôöé AdminisÔÇª Ôöé disabled Ôöé
Ôöé 5  Ôöé edi-frontendserver      Ôöé N/A     Ôöé fork    Ôöé 49584    Ôöé 2D     Ôöé 0    Ôöé online   Ôöé 0%       Ôöé 56.5mb   Ôöé AdminisÔÇª Ôöé disabled Ôöé
Ôöé 4  Ôöé edi-sybase-inferface    Ôöé 0.0.1   Ôöé fork    Ôöé 31156    Ôöé 2D     Ôöé 0    Ôöé online   Ôöé 0%       Ôöé 60.2mb   Ôöé AdminisÔÇª Ôöé disabled Ôöé
ÔööÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÿ
'@ | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template -OutVariable results
```

And the output (trimmed)

```
Host     : Backendserver
Version  : 0.0.1
Mode     : fork
PID      : 60168
Uptime   : 2D
Status   : online
CPU      : 0%
Mem      : 563.4mb
User     : Adminis
Watching : disabled

Host     : Frontendserver
Version  : N/A
Mode     : fork
PID      : 25976
Uptime   : 2D
Status   : online
CPU      : 0%
Mem      : 71.3mb
User     : Adminis
Watching : disabled

Host     : Schedulingservice
Version  : N/A
Mode     : fork
PID      : 38904
Uptime   : 2D
Status   : online
CPU      : 0%
Mem      : 58.9mb
User     : Adminis
Watching : disabled
```

And it's also captured in the `$results` variable which we can use for further processing.

```
$results | Format-Table

Host                 Version Mode PID   Uptime Status CPU Mem     User    Watching
----                 ------- ---- ---   ------ ------ --- ---     ----    --------
Backendserver        0.0.1   fork 60168 2D     online 0%  563.4mb Adminis disabled
Frontendserver       N/A     fork 25976 2D     online 0%  71.3mb  Adminis disabled
Schedulingservice    N/A     fork 38904 2D     online 0%  58.9mb  Adminis disabled
edi-csv-server       0.0.1   fork 46728 2D     online 0%  54.7mb  Adminis disabled
edi-frontendserver   N/A     fork 49584 2D     online 0%  56.5mb  Adminis disabled
edi-sybase-inferface 0.0.1   fork 31156 2D     online 0%  60.2mb  Adminis disabled

$results | where Version -ne 'n/a' | select host,version,cpu,mem

Host                 Version CPU Mem    
----                 ------- --- ---    
Backendserver        0.0.1   0%  563.4mb
edi-csv-server       0.0.1   0%  54.7mb 
edi-sybase-inferface 0.0.1   0%  60.2mb
```

Here is how you'd use it reading from a file

```
$csvfile = 'C:\Users\taut\Documents\git\PM2\PM2\scripts\test.txt'
Get-Content $csvfile -Raw -Encoding UTF8 |
    ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template -OutVariable results
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex `[^\s+\w+\/\|:\.%]` in command:

```
$c -replace '/[^\s+\w+\/\|:\.%]/', ' '
```